# local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy teniendo problemas con este código me aparece que que la variable especificada en la linea 242.(Marcada ):

> ```
>     totalCompra= totalCompra + int(aux2[2])*int(itemAmount)
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'totalCompra' referenced before assignment
> ```

Adjunto todo el código para que sea completo todo, si pueden ayudar gracias.

```
#Menu Principal
def menuPrincipal():
    print ("Menu Principal- Elija una accion:")#Funciona
    print ("1- Agregar o quitar un producto")#Funciona
    print ("2- Realizar una compra")
    print ("3- Actualizar Precios")#Funciona
    print ("4- Articulo mas vendido")
    print ("5- Productos Vencidos")#Funciona
    print ("6- Articulo mas Vendido segun la clasificacion")
    print ("7- Ver listado de productos")#Funciona
    print ("8- Salir")#Funciona
    choice=input()

#Muestra agregarQuitar
    if choice=='1':
        agregarQuitar()

 #Muestra top Venta
    if choice=='4':
        filtrarVentas()
        topVenta()

    #Muestra vencidos
    if choice =="5":
        print(vencidos)
        menuPrincipal()



    #Muestra el listado
    if choice=="7":
        verListado()
        menuPrincipal()


    #Sale del programa
    if choice=="8":
        quit()

    #Actualizar un precio
    if choice=='3':
        actualizarPrecio()

#Compra del cliente
    if choice=="2":
        compraCliente()



#Define todo
productos={20:('coca','10','2','2/2/21','b')}
vencidos={}
ventas=[]
Factura={}
record={}
totalCompra=0
totalCompra1=0

#Menu de Agregar o Quitar algun producto
def agregarQuitar():

#Login basico para verificar identidad
    print("Verifique Su Identidad")
    print("Ingrese nombre de usuario:")
    usr=input()
    print ("Ingrese su contraseña:")
    pwd=input()

#Cuando se chequea sigue adelante o vuelve al menu principal
    if usr=="admin" and pwd=="admin":
        print ("Seleccione que quiere hacer")
        print ("1-Agregar un producto")
        print ("2-Quitar un producto")
        adminChoice=input()
        if adminChoice=="1":
            print ("Ingrese la clave del producto")
            clave=input()
            print ("Ingrese los valores. SEPARADOS POR UN ESPACIO EN EL SIGUIENTE FORMATO")
            print("descripcion,stock,precio unitario,vencimiento dd/mm/aa ,tipo de producto")

#Hace una lista con las caracteristicas del codigo de identificacion.
            values=input().split()

#Agrego el producto al diccionario
            productos[int(clave)]=values


#Chekeo de vencidos luego de agregar:
            import time
            currentDate=(time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")).split('/')
            date= productos[int(clave)]
            ix=list(date)
            pi= ix[3].split('/')

            if pi[2]< currentDate[2]:
                vencidos[int(clave)]=values
                del productos[int(clave)]
            if pi[2]>= currentDate[2] and pi[1]< currentDate[1]:
                vencidos[int(clave)]= values
                del productos[int(clave)]
            if pi[2]>= currentDate[2] and pi[1]>= currentDate[1] and pi[0]< currentDate[0]:
                vencidos [int(clave)] = values
                del productos[int(clave)]


#Chekea si el producto fue eliminado por estar vencido o no
            for c in productos.keys():
                if c == int(clave):
                    print ("El producto fue agregado exitosamente")
                else:
                    print ("El producto esta vencido, no se pudo agregar")

            menuPrincipal()

#Menu de eliminar un producto
    if adminChoice=="2":
#Si no conoce la lista de productos se imprime
        print ("¿Quiere ver la lista de productos? S/N")
        rta=input()
        if rta=="s":
            print (productos)
            print ("Ingrese la clave del producto que quiere borrar:")
            deleteKey=input()
        if rta=="n":
            print ("Ingrese la clave del producto que quiere borrar:")
            deleteKey=input()

#Reconfirmacion de que quiere eliminar el producto.
        print ("¿Esta Seguro que quiere eliminar el producto?  s/n")
        adminConfirm=input()
        if adminConfirm=="s":
            del productos [deleteKey]
            print ("Producto eliminado")
            menuPrincipal()
        else:
            menuPrincipal()

    else:
        print("Error al iniciar sesion Usuario o Contraseña invalido")
        menuPrincipal()


#Funcion para actualizar el precio de un producto
def actualizarPrecio():
    print ("¿Quiere ver la lista de productos? S/N")
    rta=input()
    if rta=="s":
        print (productos)
        print ("Ingrese la clave del producto que quiere modificar:")
        modifyKey=input()
    if rta=="n":
        print ("Ingrese la clave del producto que quiere modificar:")
        modifyKey=input()

    print ("Ingrese el nuevo precio del producto:")
    newPrice=input()
    #Confirmacion de que quiere modificar el producto.
    print ("¿Esta Seguro que quiere modificar el producto?  s/n")
    adminConfirm=input()
    if adminConfirm=="s":
        #convertir la tupla a lista
        aux= productos[int(modifyKey)]
        k= list(aux)
        #Reasigna el precio que esta en esa posicion al precio nuevo.
        k[2]= newPrice
        #Vuelve a hacerlo tupla y se mete en el diccionario
        i=tuple(k)
        productos[int(modifyKey)] = i
        print ("Producto modificado")
        menuPrincipal()
    else:
        menuPrincipal()


#Funcion para ver los productos
def verListado():
    print (productos)

def Options():
    print('1- Seguir comprando')
    print ('2- Terminar Compra')
    chosenOption=input()
    if chosenOption =='1':
        compraCliente()
    if chosenOption == '2':
        funcionTicket()

def actualizarStock():
    newStock= int(aux2[1]) - int(itemAmount)
    aux2[1]=newStock
    val1=tuple(aux2)
    productos[c]=val1

def filtrarVentas():
    for c in ventas:
        cant=ventas.count(c)
        record[c]=cant

def registroVentas():
    ventas.append(aux2[0])

def envioDomicilio():
    print('¿Quiere que le envien la compra a domicilio?')
    print ('s/n')
    envioChoice=input()
    if envioChoice == 's':
        print('ingrese nombre,direccion,telefono, separados por una coma.')
        datosCliente=input().split(',')
        print('el pedido sera enviado a ',datosCliente[1])
        menuPrincipal()
    else:
        menuPrincipal()



#Funcion de Compra de Cliente:
def compraCliente():
    print ('Ingrese que producto quiere llevar')
    customerChoice=input()
    for c in productos.keys():
        aux=productos[c]
        aux2=list(aux)
        compareValue=aux2[0]
        if compareValue==customerChoice:
            print('Ingrese cuantos quiere llevar')
            itemAmount=input()
            itemStock=aux2[1]
            if int(itemAmount)<= int(itemStock):
                #Check Expiration Date
                itemExpiration= aux2[3].split('/')
                import time
                currentDate=time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y").split('/')
                if str(int(currentDate[0])+7)== itemExpiration[0]:
                    #Hacer 10% de descuento
                    #ERROR PORQUE NO CALCULA LOS CAMBIOS DE MES.
                    totalCompra= totalCompra +(int(aux2[2])*int(itemAmount))*0.9
                    facturaDescuento()
                    registroVentas()
                    actualizarStock()
                    Options()
                else:
  ERROR--->         totalCompra1= totalCompra1 + int(aux2[2])*int(itemAmount)
                    facturaRegular()
                    registroVentas()
                    actualizarStock()
                    Options()

                if itemAmount > itemStock:
                    print('No hay suficiente cantidad')
                    print('Hay que reponer')
                    print('¿Desea ver cuantas unidades hay?')
                    print (' s/n ' )
                    e=input()
                    if e=='s':
                        print (itemStock)
                        Options()

def imprimirTicket():
    print(factura)
    print('-------')
    print('total:',totalCompra+totalCompra1)




menuPrincipal()
```

Answer (score 11):

Simplifico el código para que lo entiendas mejor::

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a = 0

def foobar():
    a = a + 2
    print(a)

foobar()
```

El código que he escrito arriba, genera el mismo error. El problema está en que en **python** cuando defines (o sea asignas valor) una variable local (a la función foobar en este caso) con un mismo nombre que una variable preexistente en un ámbito superior, ésta última variable deja de existir dentro de la función. Por tanto, dentro de foobar "a" no existe antes de que hagas:

```
a = a + 2
```

y, claro, genera fallo. La solución es declarar dentro de la función que "a" existe fuera:

```
def foobar():
    global a
    a = a + 2
    print(a)
```

Comment: pero si la variable a existe en mas de una función tocaria declararla varias veces, eso no haria que tuviera las mismas propiedades de una variable no global?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el razonamiento. Si en todas las funciones, usas ``global a``, en todas las funciones estarás usando y alterando el valor de la variable global ``a``.